# hapi-auth-basic validate function doesn't work properly when the function contains asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, basic-authentication, hapi.js

I am using hapi-auth-basic version 5.0.0 for authentication in my hapi server v17.2.2. It gives error when there is asynchronous code inside the validation function. What to do?

I used hapi-cli to create a hapi project. It has a folder called policies which contains the validate functions used for authentication.
I modified it a little bit to my convenience as follows

```
const Boom = require('boom');
const User = Models.User

module.exports = async (request, email, password, h) => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        return {
          isValid: false,
          credentials: null
        }
    }
    User.findOne({
        email,
        role: 'admin'
    }).exec((err, currentUser) => {
        if (!currentUser || err) {
            return Boom.badRequest('You must be admin user');
        }
        request.adminUser = currentUser;
        return {
          isValid: true,
          credentials: currentUser
        }
    });
};
```

I want to authenticate the user if the given email address is present and the user role is admin
But I am getting the following error

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property `isValid` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.authenticate (/home/sruthi/IoTRL/hapi-api/node_modules/hapi-auth-basic/lib/index.js:64:56)
    at <anonymous>
```

When I returned just `{isValid: true, credentials: {email}}` like this

```
module.exports = async (request, email, password, h) => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        return {
          isValid: false,
          credentials: null
        }
    }
    return {
      isValid: true,
      credentials: {email}
    }
};
```

without the asynchronous code getting the user from database, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function returns nothing, Mongoose exec((err, user)) is out of your function's scope, and also you are already using async functions, why don't you use await syntax.

Here, a quick rewrite of your code.

```
module.exports = async (request, email, password, h) => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        return {
          isValid: false,
          credentials: null
        }
    }

    try
    {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email, role: 'admin' }).exec();

        // user doesn't exist
        if(!user){
            return Boom.unauthorized('You must be admin user');
        }

        // we found the user, let's authenticate
        request.adminUser = currentUser;
        return {
          isValid: true,
          credentials: currentUser
        }
    } catch(e){
        // handle other errors
        return Boom.badRequest(e);
    }   
};
```